# fancybox move to bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have fancybox 2.0+ working with inline hidden html div, I was seeking to have a link within the html area to goto bottom of the page

So the fancybox is opened I need a link within fancy box to scroll to the bottom of the fancybox

I tried

```
jQuery('.fancybox-wrap').animate({  scrollTop: jQuery("#lpsubmit").offset().top  }, 2000);
```

and

```
jQuery('html,body').animate({  scrollTop: jQuery("#lpsubmit").offset().top  }, 2000);
```

Lpsumbit(id of the button) is the button at bottom which user needs to click both above doesnt seems to work for me. If anyone has done something similar it will be a great help

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rigids/ps8J8/1/

EDIT
http://jsfiddle.net/fG4eT/2 explains my actual issue sorry for not explaining earlier in question as I thought it would solve the actual purpose the slide down issue contradicts with the slidetoggle i need

Comment: @jfk any idea on this

Comment: can you add the fancy box JS library that you are using to your jsbin page ?

Comment: @June : I am not sure you understand what `slideToggle()` does. And of course, your original post doesn't show or mention any related code or use of such method.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/fG4eT/2 explains my actual issue sorry for not explaining earlier in question as I thought it would solve the actual purpose the slide down issue contradicts with the slidetoggle i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you found a problem to this issue. But here is my take on it.

The main problem is that fancybox uses the CSS property `position: fixed;` to show the overlay and also adds `overflow: hidden;` to `<body>` while it's being displayed, which locks your page and prevent it from scrolling properly.

The way to go around this issue is to scroll the container of the fancybox rather than the page.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ramynasr/fG4eT/22/).

```
jQuery('#anyID').click(function () {
    jQuery('#scrolltobottom').slideToggle('2000', function () {
        $(".fancybox-overlay-fixed").animate({
            scrollTop: $(document).height()
        }, 2000);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you it works, depite getting -2 I think it still will help someone for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can not use same ID more than one in the same html file.
You can use animate property to make it working.
Here is the jsfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ps8J8/6/)

```
$("#scrolltobottom").click(function(e){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fG4eT/2/ explains my actual issue sorry for not explaining earlier in question as I thought it would solve the actual purpose the slide down issue contradicts with the slidetoggle i need

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fG4eT/2/ the code you made doesnt works with slidetoggle where actual div is hidden and if the height of the page is different the code will not work

Comment: It means you want to solve it by using slidetoggle? ans how you can say [1]: jsfiddle.net/fG4eT/2 will not work when height is different, it will work as it is not having any hard coded height.

Comment: I ahve a login button at the top on click of that at the very bottom of the page login form slidedown so I want on click of the button at top the form should slidetoggle at bottom as well screen to move down automatically. hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use jQuery scrollTop on `$('.fancybox-overlay')`.

Animated:

```
$('#link').click(function () {
    $('.fancybox-overlay').animate({
        scrollTop: (($('.fancybox-wrap').outerHeight() - $('.fancybox-overlay').outerHeight()))
    }, 1000);
});
```

Unanimated:

```
$('#link').click(function () {
    $('.fancybox-overlay').scrollTop((($('.fancybox-wrap').outerHeight() - $('.fancybox-overlay').outerHeight())));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer based on your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/fG4eT/2):

```
$("#anyID").click(function() {
    var container = $('.fancybox-overlay');
    var scrollTo = $("#scrolltobottom");

    // Or you can animate the scrolling:
    container.animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
    }, 5000);
    return false;
});
```

In fiddle fork: http://jsfiddle.net/AB4Yh/12/